# Get value from reference in C++

Tags: c++

I have the problem to get a reference to an int (from a collection of ints, QList). But I need the value to call another function which uses call-by-value.

```
int my_var = collection[i];

nextFunction(my_var); --> ERROR no matching function ... (int&) ...
```

How do I get the value from this reference or convert it?

The signatufe of the function I want to call looks like this:

```
nextFunction(int id, ...);
```

and its actually a constructor.

Comment: What's the signature of `nextFunction`?

Comment: Post the signature of `nextFunction` and the *actual* compilation error.

Comment: I'm sorry but the problem turns out to come form an entirely different argument than I was thinking. I apparently passed on Object instead of a reference in one of the other arguments, that was the reason. This question makes no sense since.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is different than converting reference to value. Even if a function uses call by value method it will happily take a reference variable. I have tried that on visual studio and its works fine.

During function call the compiler generally does a type checking on the params. I think you should look at the type of the value returned by the collections[i]. 
Your compiler error indicates that there is type mismatch. I don't think it has anything to do with call by value and call by reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass the value to nextFunction you need to add a const to your method

```
nextFunction(double& par);
```

will cause your error.

```
nextFunction(const double& par);
```

or

```
nextFunction(double par);
```

would cause automatic conversion.
So if you really want par to be changed inside of nextFunction you need

```
nextFunction(int& par);
```